# Mouse wheel press - what name has an event described and how to listen for it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

If you press your mousewheel (sometimes called as mouse3 or scrollwheel), it triggers all-directions-scrolling - try it on website with scrollbar.

Pressed initiates event, and when mouse is moved it does scroll.

How to listen for that press and scrolling events?

Answer (score 0):

For clicking the mousewheel

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 2) {
        alert('You just click the middle button');
    }
})
```

For scrolling the page

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    alert('You just scroll the page');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The event that is triggered is called "mousedown", while the information about which mouse button was pressed is stored in `event.button`. A value of `0` corresponds to the left mouse button, a value of `1` refers to the middle mouse button.

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.button === 1) {
        console.log("Middle mouse button pressed");
        scrollByMouseMovement = true;
    } else {
        scrollByMouseMovement = false;
    }
});
```

Then, listen to the "pointermove" event to catch the mouse movement.

```
window.addEventListener('pointermove', function (event) {
    if (scrollByMouseMovement) {
        console.log("Scrolling by mouse movement...");
        // ... code for scrolling page programmatically ...
    }
});
```